# Recursive directory tree printer

Tags: haskell, file-system

I wrote this program that recursively prints all the files and directories starting at the current directory:

```
import Data.Tree (Tree (..))
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, getCurrentDirectory, getDirectoryContents)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  currentDirectory <- getCurrentDirectory
  tree <- tree currentDirectory "."
  printTree 0 tree

printTree :: Int -> Tree FilePath -> IO ()
printTree indent tree = do
  putStrLn $ (replicate indent ' ' ++ rootLabel tree)
  mapM_ (printTree $ indent + 2) (subForest tree)

treeHelper :: FilePath -> IO [Tree FilePath]
treeHelper path =
  let filter' = filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) in
  do
    contents <- getDirectoryContents path
    trees <- mapM (tree path) (filter' contents)
    return trees

tree :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO (Tree FilePath)
tree parent path =
  let fullPath = (parent ++ "/" ++ path) in
  do
    isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fullPath
    case isDirectory of
      False -> return $ Node path []
      True -> treeHelper fullPath >>= (return . Node (path ++ "/"))
```

If you run it, it might print something like this:

```
./
  dist/
    build/
      autogen/
        cabal_macros.h
        Paths_Tree.hs
      tree/
        tree
        tree-tmp/
          Main.hi
          Main.o
    package.conf.inplace
    setup-config
  Setup.lhs
  tree.cabal
  Tree.hs
```

I think this is pretty nifty. It's a toy program, so I purposefully left out stuff like error checking and symlink handling and etc. How would you improve this program? Am I duplicating functionality available in a library? Are there places where the code could be tighter? Is my Haskell style not up to snuff?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use `unfoldTree` (or `unfoldTreeM` here) to build `Data.Tree`:

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Directory
import System.FilePath
import Data.Tree


dirTree :: FilePath -> IO (Tree FilePath)
dirTree root = unfoldTreeM step (root,root)
    where step (f,c) = do
            fs <- getDirectoryContents f
            ds <- filterM doesDirectoryExist fs
            return (c, [(f </> d, d) | d <- ds, d /= "." && d /= ".."])

main :: IO ()
main = do
  t <- dirTree "."
  putStrLn $ drawTree t
```

**Update**: As Björn Lindqvist correctly noted in his edit suggestion, my use of `doesDirectoryExist` doesn't work here (it uses directory *names* instead of directory *paths*).

The correct version of `dirTree` would be:

```
dirTree :: FilePath -> IO (Tree FilePath)
dirTree root = unfoldTreeM step (root,root)
    where step (p, c) = do
            isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist p
            fs <- if isDirectory then getDirectoryContents p else return []
            return (c, [(p </> f, f) | f <- fs, f `notElem` [".", ".."]])
```

Answer (score 7):

Paths should be manipulated with functions from `System.FilePath`.  You can also move `let`'s inside the `do`'s, replace the `case` on `Bool` with an `if`, and squeeze out the helper function with `<$>`.

```
import Control.Applicative
import System.FilePath ((</>), addTrailingPathSeparator)

tree :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO (Tree FilePath)
tree parent path = do
  let fullPath = parent </> path
  isDirectory <- doesDirectoryExist fullPath
  if isDirectory
    then do
      paths <- filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) <$> getDirectoryContents fullPath
      Node (addTrailingPathSeparator path) <$> mapM (tree fullPath) paths
  else return $ Node path []
```